# Check BitmapDescriptor for null

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to check [BitmapDescriptor](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptor.html) for null.

The documentation for [BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html#fromAsset%28java.lang.String%29)  states that:

> Returns
>   the BitmapDescriptor that was loaded from the asset or null if failed to load.

```
    BitmapDescriptor bd = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset("markerimages/filename.png");
    if (bd == null) {
        // doSomething...
    }
```

Despite this, I am unable to catch BitMapDescriptor in a null state - even when I pass a filename that does not exist, the fromAsset method does not return a null.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? I mean: have you put a breakpoint on that line to see what it actually is returning?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the fromAsset method doesn't return null, but perhaps returns the same as defaultMarker() returns.  (i.e. the documentation is wrong)

I'd check whether the value you get for a (presumably non-existent) asset is either '==' or .Equals the defaultMarker().  That could be how you detect a non-existent asset.

Comment: burntsugar and I found that using the returned BitmapDescriptor causes it to explode further down the track, suggesting that while it's a BitmapDescriptor instance, its not backed by a valid bitmap. the class is a "handle" and has no methods. we were able to detect the (non)existence of a resource by loading the stream directly using another method, and then calling fromAsset() if InputStream != null. that worked, but its a work around. i can only assume the doco is wrong. attempting to load a non-existent resource must be enough of a corner case that it's not been picked up before.

Answer (score 0):

I have found, contrary to documentation, BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset(String) does not return null if the specified asset does not exist. I am currently implementing a work around where I pre-load the list of assets which do exist using AssetManager.list(""). Then, for an asset name in question I search the cached list of assets to determine whether the specified asset exists or not.

This was the least resource intensive approach I could thnk of since I could not depend on a null return when the asset did not exist.